# Detach HTML element and open in a new browser window without breaking styles

Tags: javascript, html, web, ecmascript-6, polymer

I am building a SPA with Polymer3 (Javascript ES6 with imports). My application needs to move some widgets to new browser windows. Then users can move some widgets to multiple screens when having multiple monitors.Following is the procedure i follow to detach element from existing window and attach it to new window.

1. Detach element using HTML DOM removeChild() Method
2. Create new Window using  window.open("", "myWindow",'modal=yes');
3. Attache new element to new window using newWindow.document.body.appendChild(element);

Problem

1. When the element is in the new window it does not take parent window styles.
2. When the element is detached some of the parent window styles are broken.

Can anyone please instruct on a way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I would use a different approach to your problem. It does not take the "parent" window styles because that's not how browsers work. Either include your stylesheets in the new window or create dedicated URLs that load just one widget and then open that URL in a new window.

Comment: Then it will load as a different application instance. Isn't it? But i want my child window to share parent windows global variables and connections. eg:- Child window should communicate with server using a websocket created in parent application and it uses some configurations saved as global variables in parent window application

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure it would work, but you can open the same window you already have open twice. Second time, you open it with additional parameter.
E.g

```
// your app root url -> http://localhost/mySPA

widget1Window = window.open("http://localhost/mySPA/widget1", "myWindow",'modal=yes');

and in your app template you map that route to specific widget.
e.g in pseudo angular2 code, both routes load the same page, but with 
different conditions in route.

<app>
 <maincontent>
  <common-stuff-between-windows></common-stuff-between-windows>
  <widget1 *ngIf="showWidget1"></widget1>
  <widget2 *ngIf="showWidget2"></widget2>
 </maincontent>
</app>
and in your javascript routing you would check if the route contains
a widget reference. If yes, then make that part of the template visible.
```

Comment: Then it will load as a different application instance. Isn't it? But i want my child window to share parent windows global variables and connections. eg:- Child window should communicate with server using a websocket created in parent application and it uses some configurations saved as global variables in parent window application

Comment: Yes, but it shouldn't matter. If your app is well built/configured then creating the second instance will load the same configuration and create the same socket connection with no extra work. You can then use that socket to sync actions between instanses...or you can "poll" localstorage to share variables/information between the instances. PS, i think that your current approach not only loads your parent window's styles, but it also doesnt load your parent window javascript. E.g do your components work in the new window? (ignoring the css)

Comment: Finally i came up with the following approach. I loaded the popup window as another application instance. I used window.opener to access the parent window global variables and connections.